# Batch file: adding prefix to all lines of all files in a directory

Tags: string, file, batch-file, line, prefix

I have a list of files in a directory D:\test and I want to add by using a batch file a prefix BLA_ to each line of each file in D:\test. After this process, files can be moved to D:\test\processed\ and the file name should also be changed to BLA_file name.

It doesn't sound really difficult, but I did not manage to create a working batch file. Hope someone can help me!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

suggestion with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed -i "s/^/BLA_/" D:\Test\*
for %%a in (D:\Test\*) do move "%%~a" "D:\test\processed\BLA_%%~a"
```

Comment: Hi Endoro. Thanks for your answer. Since it is on a business terminal server I'm not sure whether I should install sed for Windows or not. Is there also an easy way without using sed?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "inputFolder=d:\test"
    set "outputFolder=%inputFolder%\processed"

    for %%a in ("%inputFolder%\*"
    ) do (for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%b in (
        'findstr /n "^" "%%~fa" ^& del /q "%%~fa" ^>nul 2^>nul'
    ) do (echo BLA_%%c))>"%outputFolder%\BLA_%%~nxa"

    endlocal
```

For each file in the input folder, read input file, delete input file and for each line in the selected input file (`findstr /n` is used to avoid empty line skip), echo the line with the prefix into the output file.

Comment: Hi MC ND. Thanks! I used your code (only changed delims to ; since delimiter is semicolon), and now the first column of the file is replaced by BLA_ instead of this prefix is added the to first column (so BLA_hello if hello used to be the first column). Any advice how I can change this?

Comment: @Hans, to avoid empty lines removal (the default `for` behaviour), `findstr` is used to numerate the lines. To split the number from the content, the colon is used as a delimiter between the number of the line (in var %%b) and the content of the line (in var %%c). When you changed it to a semicolon, the code can not separate the two values, so, all the content (and number) goes into %%b. But what the code outputs is %%c, so, no content